# Build and execute function on the fly [PHP]

Tags: php

I have a function defined as:

```
function foo($params)
{
    echo "Hello ".$params;
}
```

Then, in another file, I have:

```
$functionName = "foo";
$functionParams = "World";

include("./path_to_file_where_above_function_exists.php");

$functionName($functionParams);
```

This outputs, as expected:

```
Hello World
```

So far so good, what I want to know is how can I check if the function exists in the other file? For example, if I change:

```
$functionName = "foo";
```

to

```
$functionName = "bla";
```

The code throws no errors. Any help on how to properly handle errors in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into [function_exists()](http://php.net/function_exists)?

Comment: go through link http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: you can get filename print (new ReflectionFunction("foo"))->getFileName();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the ability to call a function with help [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php). For example:

```
function foo($params)
{
    echo "Hello ".$params;
}

$functionName = "foo";
$functionParams = "World";
if (!is_callable($functionName)) {
    echo "{$funtionName} is not a function"
}
```